# dummy function for pandas (sklearn.pipeline)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline, sklearn-pandas

```
import pandas as pd

def dummies_(df_e):
    df_e = pd.get_dummies(df_e)
    df_e.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

dummies_(df)
df.head()

    customerID  gender  SeniorCitizen   Partner Dependents  tenure  PhoneService    MultipleLines   InternetService OnlineSecurity  ... DeviceProtection    TechSupport StreamingTV StreamingMovies Contract    PaperlessBilling    PaymentMethod   MonthlyCharges  TotalCharges    Churn
185 1024-GUALD  Female  0   Yes No  1   No  No phone service    DSL No  ... No  No  No  No  Month-to-month  Yes Electronic check    24.80   24.8    Yes
2715    0484-JPBRU  Male    0   No  No  41  Yes Yes No  No internet service ... No internet service No internet service No internet service No internet service Month-to-month  Yes Bank transfer (automatic)   25.25   996.45  No
3825    3620-EHIMZ  Female  0   Yes Yes 52  Yes No  No  No internet service ... No internet service No internet service No internet service No internet service Two year    No  Mailed check    19.35   1031.7  No
1807    6910-HADCM  Female  0   No  No  1   Yes No  Fiber optic No  ... Yes No  No  No  Month-to-month  No  Electronic check    76.35   76.35   Yes
132 8587-XYZSF  Male    0   No  No  67  Yes No  DSL No  ... No  Yes No  No  Two year    No  Bank transfer (automatic)   50.55   3260.1  No
```

Nothing happen and changed!! Is there is a thing that I may miss looked?

----updated----
it works if i put return df_e on the function dummies_(), but if i try to put it on sklearn pipeline an error will occur. Any idea to tackle this issue?

```
def dummies_(df_e):
    df_e = pd.get_dummies(df_e)
    df_e.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
    return df_e

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pre_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('dummy',dummies_(df2)),
])

prepared_data = pre_pipeline.fit_transform(df2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-315-ee004e435831> in <module>
----> 7     ('dummy',dummies_(df2)),
      8 ])
      9 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in __init__(self, steps, memory)
    117     def __init__(self, steps, memory=None):
    118         self.steps = steps
--> 119         self._validate_steps()
    120         self.memory = memory
    121 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _validate_steps(self)
    171             raise TypeError("Last step of Pipeline should implement fit. "
    172                             "'%s' (type %s) doesn't"
--> 173                             % (estimator, type(estimator)))
    174 
    175     @property

TypeError: Last step of Pipeline should implement fit. '      SeniorCitizen  Partner  Dependents  tenure  PhoneService  \
185               0        1           0       1             0   
2715              0        0           0      41             1   
3825              0        1           1      52             1   
1807              0        0           0       1             1   
132               0        0           0      67             1   
1263              1        1           0      68             1   
3732              0        1           1      23             1   
1672              0        1           1      72             1   
811               0        0           0      70             1   
2526              0        0           0       1             1   
2892              0        0           0       1             1   
4129              0        1           1      34             1   
2622              1        1           1      28             1   
3801              1        0           0      18             1   
4357              0        1           0      15             1   
6179              1        0           0      11             1   
5275              0        0           0      11             1   
4640              0        1           1       1             1   
833               0        1           1      37             1   
5194              0        0           1      22             1   
3328              0        0           0       1             1   
101               0        1           1       1             1   
6298              0        1           1      46             1   
1090              0        0           0      51             1   
1744              0        1           0      41             1   
6486              0        1           0       5             1   
6370              0        0           0      45             1   
1882              0        1           1      29             1   
3469              1        0           0      15             1   
2310              0        0           0      72             0   
...             ...      ...         ...     ...           ...   
6848              0        1           0       2             1   
710               0        0           0       1             1   
2357              0        1           0      67             1   
6493              0        1           0      17             0   
558               0        0           0      11             1   
5927              0        0           0      51             1   
2306              0        0           0       3             1   
1371              1        0           0       1             1   
5872              0        0           1       1             1   
6629              1        1           0      72             1   
907               0        0           0      19             1   
6226              0        0           0      65             1   
4376              0        0           0      45             1   
5970              0        1           0       5             1   
6253              0        0           0      56             0   
2453              1        0           0       4             1   
4715              0        0           0      64             1   
1872              0        1           1      41             1   
5773              0        0           0      35             1   
3773              0        0           0       1             0   
926               1        0           0       3             1   
2481              1        1           0      61             1   
5481              1        0           0       1             1   
3404              0        0           1      35             1   
15                0        1           1      69             1   
6366              0        1           0      64             1   
315               0        1           1      51             1   
2439              0        1           1      17             1   
5002              0        1           1      69             0   
1161              0        0           1       1             0   
[1409 rows x 42 columns]' (type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>) doesn't
```

error occur as I tried to applied the function on the pipeline. any idea or suggestion on how to make it works in sklearn.pipeline?

Comment: Try adding `return df_e` in the end of the function, and call the function with `df = dummies_(df)`

Comment: @Aryerez you don't need any return because you change df inplace. I don't see any mistakes in this code.

Comment: @MykolaZotko maybe you are right theoretically, but I've made that change physically, and it worked...

Comment: @MykolaZotko I don't think pd.get_dummies is inplace.

Comment: @ec2604 Your are right. This is the problem.

Comment: @Aryerez it works but the problem is when im trying to use the function in sklearn pipeline. sklearn doesnt work well with pandas dataframe.